# Implementing Conversation Time Measuring App Slack

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm fairly new to the Slack API. I wanted to write a slack app that does that measures the amount of time spent conversing. More specifically, I want to **measure the amount of time between the first and last message sent in conversations with 5+ messages from different people in which the average time between a message and a response is < 1 min**

Can anyone think of a way to do this with the Slack API? I'm not looking for an implementation; I just want some advice on which API to use and suggestions from those experienced in the Slack API.

Comment: Why the down votes? Rather than merely down voting, do you mind telling me what to change in my question so I can edit and resubmit?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the list of all messages from a conversation / channel by calling [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) in the Slack API. Each message will include the user ID (`user`) of the sender and its timestamp (`ts`), which should enable you to calculate the information you need.

Note that the user that installs your app needs to have access to the conversation for this to work.